# Redux form: edit the whole JSON content

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have a React Redux Form used to edit several fields using the  component. But I also want to be able to edit the whole content, including all the fields, as a JSON text in a textarea.
Is there a way to bind a textarea to the whole content converted as a string?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the value of the textarea to the object you pull out of Redux and then stringify it. It won't be formatted as human readable though. May need to find a library for that.

Comment: I found how to get the valuea with the reduxForm().values, but don't know how to set it back when the textares content gets modified by the user (onChange). Any help appreciated here.